# How to draw a line in Sprite-kit

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit, skshapenode

How can one draw a line in Sprite-kit? For example if I want to draw a line in cocos2d, I could easily using  `ccDrawLine();`

Is there an equivalent in sprite-kit?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Using [SKShapeNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKShapeNode) you can draw line or any shape.

```
SKShapeNode *yourline = [SKShapeNode node];
CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 100.0, 100.0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 50.0, 50.0);
yourline.path = pathToDraw;
[yourline setStrokeColor:[SKColor redColor]];
[self addChild:yourline];
```

**Equivalent for Swift 4:**

```
var yourline = SKShapeNode()
var pathToDraw = CGMutablePath()
pathToDraw.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0))
pathToDraw.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0))
yourline.path = pathToDraw
yourline.strokeColor = SKColor.red
addChild(yourline)
```

Comment: no correction at all, Waruna should give it a tick as its correct.

Comment: @Smick - Waruna will accept answer buddy whenever he want...dont worry.. its correct answer.. :)

Comment: can you try solve this - its a good question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214040/how-can-you-create-a-glow-around-a-sprite-via-skeffectnode

Comment: may be this will help http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/01/uilabels-with-neon-effect/

Comment: You should use SKColor, on iOS that compiles to UIColor, on OSX to NSColor. So it works on both platforms.

Comment: Is it possible to change the line's thickness ?

Comment: Swift 2.2 - SKShapeNode still sucks.

Comment: Don't forget to end with `CGPathRelease(pathToDraw);` or you will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 11):

Using `SKShapeNode` I was able to do this.

```
// enter code here
SKShapeNode *line = [SKShapeNode node];

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 50.0, 40.0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 120.0, 400.0);

line.path = path;
[line setStrokeColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[self addChild:line];
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3 for drawing line via SKShapeNode:

```
            // Define start & end point for line
            let startPoint = CGPoint.zero
            let endPoint = CGPoint.zero

            // Create line with SKShapeNode
            let line = SKShapeNode()
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: startPoint)
            path.addLine(to: endPoint)
            line.path = path.cgPath
            line.strokeColor = UIColor.white
            line.lineWidth = 2
```

Answer (score 8):

If you only want a line, sort of how people use UIViews for lines (only), then you can just use a `SKSpriteNode`

```
SKSpriteNode* line = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(160.0, 2.0)];
[line setPosition:CGPointMake(136.0, 50.0))];
[self addChild:line];
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the equivalent code in SWIFT:

```
    let pathToDraw:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    let myLine:SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(path:pathToDraw)

    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, 100.0, 100)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, 50, 50)

    myLine.path = pathToDraw
    myLine.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()

    self.addChild(myLine)
```

Converted from to @Rajneesh071's objective c code sample.

Answer (score 5):

I found this post while trying to draw a line on each mouseDown, of the example xCode / **OS X** / Game (aka SpriteKit)/ Application.

You can copy/paste this code into GameScene.swift.  It should draw a line on each mouse-down event by user. Looks 'etch-a-sketch'-style.

[image]

```
import SpriteKit

var lastPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
var newPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0)


class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"default")
        myLabel.text = "SKSpriteNode Draw Lines";
        myLabel.fontSize = 15;
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        /* Called when a mouse click occurs */

        let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)
        newPoint = location

        let pathToDraw:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
        let myLine:SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(path:pathToDraw)


        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, newPoint.x, newPoint.y)
        lastPoint = newPoint

        myLine.path = pathToDraw
        myLine.strokeColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

        self.addChild(myLine)
    }
}
```

For the newbies, this is what my xCode project looks like:
[image]

For the *small handful* **iOS** of folks.  Same code as above ported to **touchBegan** of the example **iOS** / Game (aka SpriteKit) / Application default project. 
[image]

> Put this code in your GameScene.swift file

```
import SpriteKit

var lastPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
var newPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0)


class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"default")
        myLabel.text = "SKSpriteNode Draw Lines";
        myLabel.fontSize = 15;
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        newPoint = location

        let pathToDraw:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
        let myLine:SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(path:pathToDraw)


        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, newPoint.x, newPoint.y)
        lastPoint = newPoint

        myLine.path = pathToDraw
        myLine.strokeColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        self.addChild(myLine)
   }}}
```

[image: sunflower drawing]

Enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my Swift 4 function to add a Line between two points:

```
func drawLine(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) {
    let line = SKShapeNode()
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addLines(between: [from, to])
    line.path = path
    line.strokeColor = .black
    line.lineWidth = 2
    addChild(line)
}
```

Hope it helps!!