# SKLabelNode and it customization

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I started work with sprite-kit and want to understand how create interesting effects for text. Because we used it in many screens.

I want write text as well as on this picture:

[image]

Only gold effect. Maybe some of you have been created similar effect.

Thank you for answers!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think this is specific programming problem.

Comment: Yes it is a programming question but you have not shown what, if anything, you have tried to make this happen. This question is also very broad in its scope as it has numerous possible solutions. Your question is also not very clear as you do not specify in what context you want this code to work. Look at this previous Q&A to point you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214040/how-can-you-create-a-glow-around-a-sprite-via-skeffectnode