# Draw Vertical line in UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
UIView * lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, dialogContainer.bounds.size.height - buttonHeight - buttonSpacerHeight, dialogContainer.bounds.size.width, buttonSpacerHeight)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:198.0/255.0 green:198.0/255.0 blue:198.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
[dialogContainer addSubview:lineView];
```

I have used this code to draw horizontal line on UIView. How can I add Vertical line to UIView?

Comment: Change your `CGRectMake` methods to create a vertical box? If you're doing a bunch of custom drawing, you really ought to be using `drawRect:` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/graphicsdrawingoverview/graphicsdrawingoverview.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092011/how-to-draw-a-line-in-sprite-kit/19092449#19092449

Comment: Any reason nobody venturing towards using CALayer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UIView * lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(dialogContainer.bounds.size.width/2, 0, buttonSpacerHeight, dialogContainer.bounds.size.height)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:198.0/255.0 green:198.0/255.0 blue:198.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
[dialogContainer addSubview:lineView];
```

Comment: Adding a subview is the easy way out, but you are not really not drawing a line but rather its a subview which is not idiomatic.

Comment: I have just answered OP's question, in the way he opted for @JeslyVarghese

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass UIView and  override the drawRect: method. For example

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            //Horizontal Line
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, buttonSpacerHeight);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,0,dialogContainer.bounds.size.height - buttonHeight - buttonSpacerHeight);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,dialogContainer.bounds.size.height - buttonHeight - buttonSpacerHeight + dialogContainer.bounds.size.width,dialogContainer.bounds.size.height - buttonHeight - buttonSpacerHeight);
          //Vertical Line 
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,dialogContainer.bounds.size.height - buttonHeight - buttonSpacerHeight + dialogContainer.bounds.size.width, dialogContainer.bounds.size.height);
   CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

If you are adamant to use UIViews itself to draw vertical lines then reduce the width to a negligible value and increase the height of the UIView according to your wish.

Comment: From the Apple doc, you don't need to call super for `drawRect:`

Answer (score 2):

Just exchange your height and width to draw vertical line simple :)

```
UIView * lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, dialogContainer.bounds.size.height - buttonHeight - buttonSpacerHeight,buttonSpacerHeight, dialogContainer.bounds.size.height)];
```

other example

```
UIView *horizontalLineView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 2)];
[horizontalLineView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:horizontalLineView];


UIView *verticalLineView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 2, 100)];
[verticalLineView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:verticalLineView];
```

If you want to use coreGraphic then

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, self.frame);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, XstartPoint, ystartPoint);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,XendPoint,YendPoint);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

If you want to draw using sprite kit then [follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092011/how-to-draw-a-line-in-sprite-kit/19092449#19092449)

Comment: Mr. Tailor... dont you think that you've given so much elaborated answer??

Comment: @VineetSingh - Yes, i always try to elaborate things... :)

Answer (score 1):

taking Benny's answer to swift, you could do something like:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let spacerHeight = rect.size.height

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, (spacerHeight / 4.0))
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, 3 * (spacerHeight / 4.0))
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's documentation CGRect Returns a rectangle with the specified coordinate and size values:

```
CGRect CGRectMake (
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y,
   CGFloat width,
   CGFloat height
);
```

So try inverting what you ised to have as the width with the height

Answer (score 0):

Like you have draw horizontal line just increase the height of `UIView` and and decrease the width like the below,

```
UIView * lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, dialogContainer.bounds.size.height - buttonHeight - buttonSpacerHeight, 2, 200)];
```