# Draw a simple line on GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to draw simple line from the point I started to tap and hold to the point I move my finger to. So it's always a simple line with starting and ending point. I tried different tutorials, but it draws nothing and I do not get any errors.

This is my code within GameScene.swift

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    if let touch = touches.first {
        self.tapDown = true
        self.firstPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.tapDown = false
    self.firstPoint = CGPoint.zero
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first where self.tapDown {
        let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
        let lines = [CGPointMake(self.firstPoint.x,self.firstPoint.y),CGPointMake(currentPoint.x,currentPoint.y)]
        CGContextAddLines(context,lines,4)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
}
```

In ViewController.swift after viewDidLoad I put this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(skView.frame.size)
```

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns the current CoreGraphics drawing context. There's only a current drawing context in two scenarios:

- if you're inside a `UIView drawRect:` method (or code invoked from one, or similar functions such as those for `CALayer`s)
- if you've started your own CG context and made it "current" by calling `UIGraphicsPushContext`.

Neither of these is the case in your `touchesMoved` method, so the call returns `nil` and the subsequent drawing code fails. (I'd be surprised if it's failing silently... aren't there at least some console messages about drawing with a nil context?)

Moreover, SpriteKit doesn't draw using CoreGraphics — it renders on the GPU using OpenGL or Metal, so you don't issue drawing commands in SpriteKit so much as describe the scene that SpriteKit should draw. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092011/how-to-draw-a-line-in-sprite-kit) for an example of using `SKShapeNode` to add a line to a SpriteKit scene.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I would have written if I had written an answer.

Comment: I dont get my nil context because i called UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(skView.frame.size) in viewDidLoad. So there is actually a context available

Comment: @NovumCoder `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` is for creating an offscreen image. The drawing you do to the context you create with that function won't appear on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it working, i use SKShapeNode now, but the reason was i was using touch.locationInView instead of touch.locationInNode, which gave other coordinates for my touch point.

What is the difference between locationInView and locationInNode???

Working code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        self.tapDown = true
        self.firstPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.tapDown = false
    self.firstPoint = CGPoint.zero
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("line", usingBlock: {node, stop in
        node.removeFromParent()
    })
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("line", usingBlock: {node, stop in
        node.removeFromParent()
    })
    if let touch = touches.first where self.tapDown {
        let currentPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, self.firstPoint.x, self.firstPoint.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y)


        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode()
        shapeNode.path = path
        shapeNode.name = "line"
        shapeNode.glowWidth = 2.5
        shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        shapeNode.lineWidth = 2
        shapeNode.zPosition = 1

        self.addChild(shapeNode)
    }
}
```